Mostrar modal sin utilizar botón
Estoy tratando de mostrar un modal automáticamente con Bootrap 5:


<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Boton para modal -->
<!--     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#demo">
      Lanzar modal de fondo estático
    </button> -->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="demo" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Título del modal</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Comprendido</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 


    <!-- Mostrar modal
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#demo").modal("show");
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>



Agregué esto al final, desactivando el botón "lanzar modal" pero no muestra muestra nada.
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#demo").modal("show");
  });

Qué puede estar fallando?
EDITADO: He puesto los CDN para que puedan probar el código.

Hola @Puntay, por lo que veo no está la librería de jquery. Saludos

Te invito a guiarte por la documentación de la versión que estás usando: version 5.3.3


var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('demo'), {})
myModal.toggle()
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="modal fade" id="demo" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Título del modal</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Comprendido</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>




por que no simplemente haces una función que al cargar la página se lance el modal?
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('demo'));
    myModal.show();
  });
</script>

